# Theme Action to hook for one time only function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a custom theme. After my theme is activated/installed I need to run a one time only function that will set some options. What is the best action to hook for this?

Should I use `after_setup_theme`? My understanding is that this event/action fires on each page load so I don't think I should use this action correct?

*Ps: is it best to place this code in my functions.php file or somewhere else? (I am using the underscores theme template).

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [`after_switch_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme) action. It'll fired only on your theme activation( just one time ). So, your one time function will look:

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'my_one_time_function');

function my_one_time_function () {
    //Your code
}
```

Code goes to `functions.php` file.

P.S. If you want to run some function before deactivating theme, you can use [`switch_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/switch_theme) hook. It has same use as `after_switch_theme`.